# Using request to return a json value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `request` to make a request to this api `https://api.ipify.org/?format=json` and receive back some json like this `{"ip":"XX.XX.XXX.XX"}` from there I want to parse it and let my function's callback console.log the ip.

I'm just learning about callbacks and async so please give me any advice you can :)

```
const url = 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json';

const getMyIP = function (callback) {
  request(url, (error, body, _response) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    const ip = body["ip"];
    return ip;
  });
};


getMyIP((error, ip) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log(ip);
  }
});
```

Comment: instead of retuning `ip`, just call your callback.

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(val => {console.log(val.ip);})
.catch(e => console.log(`Error - ${e}`))
```